# Splitting a File with multiple header line

Tags: awk

I am trying to split a large file with multiple header line with the following code. Though is working; but introducing a blank line after the header in the split files. How to get rid of the blank line?

```
/^@/ {
    hdr = hdr $0 ORS
    next
}
split($NF, a, ":")
!seen[a[3]]++{
    out = a[3] ".txt"
    print hdr > out
}
{out = a[3] ".txt"
 print >> out 
 close(f)}
```

Input file

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
S1  yes yes no  yes 3y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
S17 yes no  no  yes 27y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A2
B13 no  no  no  yes 1y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A3
B5  yes yes yes yes 76y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
D1  yes yes no  no  18y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
```

Expected output

**A1.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
S1  yes yes no  yes 3y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
B5  yes yes yes yes 76y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
D1  yes yes no  no  18y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
```

**A2.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
S17 yes no  no  yes 27y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A2
```

**A3.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
B13 no  no  no  yes 1y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A3
```

But what I am getting with my script is

**A1.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information

S1  yes yes no  yes 3y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
B5  yes yes yes yes 76y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
D1  yes yes no  no  18y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
```

**A2.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information

S17 yes no  no  yes 27y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A2
```

**A3.txt**

```
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information

B13 no  no  no  yes 1y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":" }
/^@/ {
    hdr = hdr $0 ORS
    next
}
!($NF in out) {
    out[$NF] = $NF ".txt"
    printf "%s", hdr > out[$NF]
}
{
    print >> out[$NF]
    close(out[$NF])
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

```
$ head *.txt
==> A1.txt <==
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
S1  yes yes no  yes 3y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
B5  yes yes yes yes 76y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1
D1  yes yes no  no  18y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A1

==> A2.txt <==
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
S17 yes no  no  yes 27y Mother Z:AgeGroup:A2

==> A3.txt <==
@Loc: Cali
@Yr: 2017
@ST: blood
@header information
B13 no  no  no  yes 1y  Mother Z:AgeGroup:A3
```

The biggest problem in your code was the `split($NF, a, ":")` line which would trigger awk to print the current line so you must've been seeing all of your input echoed to your screen when you ran it. That would have been worth mentioning in your question. If you really wanted to use `split()` that way then you should have put it in an action block, not as a condition, i.e. `{ split($NF, a, ":") }`.

Beyond that:

1. You have `close(f)` but no variable named `f` in your code so that was doing nothing and leaving you at risk for a "too many open files" error or an execution speed reduction, and
2. You were appending ORS to the end of every header line when
   populating hdr but then also adding it again by using `print`
   instead of `printf` to output the hdr, thereby getting an extra
   blank line after every hdr block was printed.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with your shown samples, should work in any `awk` version(though I tested in GNU `awk`).

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS=":" }
FNR==NR{
  header=(header?header ORS:"") $0
  next
}
prev!=$NF{
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=$3".txt"
  print header ORS > (outputFile)
}
{
  print > (outputFile)
  prev=$NF
}
' <(awk '/^@/{print;next} {exit}' Input_file) <(grep -v '^@' Input_file | sort -t: -k1.1)
```

***Explanation of the code:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

- Firstly I am running code `awk '/^@/{print;next} {exit}' Input_file`(check in the last line's 1st argument to main `awk`). Where I am only printing lines which are starting from `@` and exiting ASAP any non `@` line comes as per shown samples. This output is being send as first set of Input to main `awk`.
- Then I am running code `grep -v '^@' Input_file | sort -t: -k1.1`, by this I am simply getting every line which is NOT starting from `@` as a 2nd input to main `awk`.
- Now in main `awk` code: I am using condition `FNR==NR` which will be TRUE when first Input(mentioned above in my 1st point) is being read. And in this block of code I am creating `awk` variable named `header` which has all the lines separated with new line to it to be used later on.
- Here `next` is very important because that will skip all further statements from here on till `FNR==NR` is TRUE.
- Once first Input is done being read and 2nd input is being read then simply checking if `prev` is NOT equal to current line's 3rd field then simply `closing` the output file(where we need to get output) in backend basically to avoid `too many files opened` Error. Setting current 3rd field's value as output file name.
- In other condition if 3rd field/column value is same then simply printing the current line into `outputFile` variable(which contains output file's name in it) and assigning value of current $3 to outputFile to be checked in next line.

Comment: @Ashi, good that you have accepted an answer, request you to check my code also once you get time.

Comment: Sure I will.  My present code (with accepted modification) is taking really long time in actual file. SO definitely going to test test this one also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are appending `ORS` every time in `hdr` field and then while using `print hdr > out` it will append another newline in the end.

You should just use `printf` like this:

```bash
printf "%s", hdr > out
```